# Router links with iron-router going to "random" places on the page

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using iron-router with a meteor application.  A strange thing is happening.  Certain links for routes (for instance /purchase) is taking me to the middle or the bottom of the page.  The behavior seems to be random.  Is there any way to ensure these take you to the top of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell the window to scroll top when navigated to a route:

```
route: {
    name: 'name'
    template: 'template'
    onAfterAction: function () {
        scrollTop();
    }
}

function scrollTop() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Strange. Pure javascript or what are you using? You can also try using scroll(), which is effectively the same.

Comment: scroll is working, weird.  I thought it was deprecated?  wtvr.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [okgrow:router-autoscroll](https://atmospherejs.com/okgrow/router-autoscroll) package.

`meteor add okgrow:router-autoscroll`

Scroll to top is okay for a forward journey in your site but If a user wants to go back it will put them back at the top of the previous page. The autoscroll package maintains the page position so when you click back it scrolls to where you were. It also has support for hash tag anchors